# Determine whether the two ODE systems are topologically equivalent (periodic orbits?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

The task is to decide, whether the following two system are topologically equivalent.
$$
\begin{cases}\dot{x}=y\\\dot{y}=-x\end{cases}\text{ and }\begin{cases}\dot{x}=x+y-x(x^2+y^2)\\\dot{y}=-x+y-y(x^2+y^2).\end{cases}
$$

My idea is the following: The first system is an harmonic oscillator since we can rewrite it as $\ddot{x}=-x$. Hence it has periodic solutions.

Next, I wanted to show that the second system does not have a periodic solution.

Using Dulac's criterion with $\phi(x,y)=1$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y-x(x^2+y^2))+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-x+y-y(x^2+y^2))=2-4(x^2+y^2)=\begin{cases}<0, & x^2+y^2>\frac{1}{2}\\>0, & x^2+y^2\leq\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}.
$$

Hence, inside and outside the circle around $(0,0)$ with radius $r=\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}$, there is no periodic solution.

The only possibilities to have a periodic orbit is that the circle itself is a periodic solution or that a periodic solution intersects the circle at least two times.

But rewriting the second system in polar coordinates $x=r\cos\varphi, y=r\sin\varphi$, we get
$$
\frac{dr}{dt}=r-r^3,\qquad \frac{d\varphi}{dt}=-1.
$$

Hence, if we are at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the circle with radius $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we have
$$
\frac{dr}{dt}>0,
$$
i.e. the angular decreases, but the radius increases. So on that circle, the vectorfield points outside the circle. Hence there is no periodic solution.

All together, system one has periodic solutions, system two has no periodic solutions, hence they are not topologically equivalent.

It would be nice to get a feedback. I am quite new with these things.

Comment: The most interesting part here is to fix your usage of Dulac's criterion. Because the second system has exactly one limit cycle. Equations for $r$ and $\varphi$ are decoupled, so it's easy to analyze dynamics.

Comment: Why does it have (exactly one) limit cycle? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Solve equations for $r$ and $\varphi$ and you'll understand everything by yourself. The mistake is quite easy to find: $x^2+y^2 > \frac{1}{2}$ is not simply-connected domain, so nor Dulac, nor Bendixson criteria are not applicable. However, you are right that you can use it for $x^2+y^2 < \frac{1}{2}$ to show the absence of limit cycles.

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you! I am learning very much from you, thanks a lot. The unit circle is a bounded, closed subset of $R^2$ and it is forward-invariant. Hence it is a limit cycle, hence a periodic orbit. Is there anything else we can say about periodic orbits of this system?

Comment: You are welcome :) we can say that this is the only one periodic orbit (~ closed trajectory) of the second system: all other trajectories except equilibrium at the origin approach this limit cycle as $t \rightarrow +\infty$. Again, all this information can be extracted from exact solution of equations for $r$ and $\varphi$.

Comment: The solution for $\varphi$ is $\varphi(t):=-t+c$. But I am not shure how to solve $\dot{r}=r-r^3$. By separation of variables I get $\int \frac{1}{r-r^3}\, dr=t+c$.

Comment: Well, this is still a sort of table integral (use partial fraction decomposition). The other way to study this system is to draw a phase line and analyze equation $\dot{r} = r - r^3$ for $r \geqslant 0$.

Comment: Ok. Anyhow: The argument is that the first system has infinitely many periodic orbits and the second one has only ONE periodic orbit. Since topological equivalence means that there is a homeomorphism that puts periodic orbits to periodic orbits, we have **no** topological equivalence here.

Comment: Yes, this is a key point. Topological equivalence is a homeomorphism, it maps closed trajectories to closed trajectories, hence no equivalence between systems with finite number of closed trajectories and with infinite number.

Comment: A related question is if the second system above  is topological equivalent to the system $\dot{x}=(x+y)(1-x^2-y^2),\quad \dot{y}=(-x+y)(1-x^2-y^2)$. I think here we do not need to go over to polar coordinates, I think it suffices to observe that the new system has many more equilibria than the first one, for example $(0,0), (1,0), (-1,0),...$ while the second one from above only has the equilibrium $(0,0)$. Allright?

Comment: Yep, seems good to me.